# domain not accessable without www prefix

Tags: domain, bind, nameserver, dns-zone

I configured `bind` nameserver for my domain on a VPS with a zone file like this:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA mydomain.com. root.mydomain.com. (
                  5     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
@   IN  A   <my IP>
www IN  CNAME   @
ns1 IN  A   <my IP>
ns2 IN  A   <my IP>
```

It works when it has `www.` prefix.
But without `www.` it shows apache's default page(`It works` page)
what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your webserver, not the nameserver.

Have it answer/listen to the plain domain name (without www).

Your probably using Apache so add a "ServerAlias" directive to the VirtualHost.

Comment: yes, Thanks; the problem was in web server's config; I used www in `ServerName` directive;